# 2D - Blender 2.92 - Fill tool is colouring only the character strokes and not area within the character

Tags: color, 2d, tools

[image][image]

I am using the grease pencil to draw my character but when I am trying to use the fill tool, it only outlines the strokes. The 'Color' layer is above the 'lines' layer. I have not been able to find any solutions for it. The alpha for stroke and fill colour is also alright.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable *Fill* in the Material properties.

[image]

Comment: Enabled the fill, still the same issue. I have attached the new screenshot in the main text, can you check it.

Answer (score 0):

I only had to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Left Click</kbd>  to fill the areas.